# Gatling : Scala - Could not find or load main class Engine

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin, maven-gatling-plugin

I am getting error Could not find or load main class Engine while running the simulation through command line. I used below command to create the jar file.

mvn clean scala:compile assembly:single package

Folder Structure

- src

  - test

    - resources
    - scala

      - testrunner

        - testsimuation1.scala
  - Engine
  - IDEPathHelper
  - Recorder

Maven - 3.6.3
Intellij - 2021.1
Scala - 2.13.10
Gatling - 3.9.0
JDK - 1.8

Below is the POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.gatling.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin-demo-scala</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.0</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <gatling.version>${project.version}</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>4.2.9</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.8.0</scala-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

 
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>    
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
          <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${gatling-mvn-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <configFolder>src/test/resources</configFolder>
            <simulationsFolder>src/test/scala</simulationsFolder>
            <resultsFolder>src/results</resultsFolder>
            <simulationClass>testrunner.testsimuation1</simulationClass>
            <jvmArgs>
              <jvmArg>-Dsimulation=testsimuation1</jvmArg>
              <jvmArg>-Xmx6g</jvmArg>
              <jvmArg>-Xms2g</jvmArg>
            </jvmArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>scala-compile-first</id>
              <phase>process-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>io.gatling.app.Gatling</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I tried moving src/test -> src/main but it threw the compilation error. Using this tool for the first time and struggling to resolve the issues.

I tried few solutions from other threads. It didn't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Engine class is only supposed to be used as a helper to launch with a "Right Click" when using your IDE.

> Using this tool for the first time and struggling to resolve the issues.

You're using maven. The way you're supposed to be running Gatling with maven is to run `mvn gatling:test`, see [`gatling-maven-plugin's documentation`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/extensions/maven_plugin/).

Whatever else you're doing with `maven-assembly-plugin` is custom development, not really related to Gatling.

Note: if you're looking for handling Gatling deployments, [Gatling Enterprise](https://gatling.io/enterprise/) is an option.